# Tableau Highlighting

Tags: regex, function, formula, tableau-api

I am using tableau tables to show some data. I want to highlight part of a string. So

```
    Column A                Column B 
    Retur                   Put Returns between Paragraphs
```

I want retur to be **highlighted** in Column B  i.e what is in Column A would show as text in column B. I want it to be highlighted.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question so that we do not suggest you what you already tried.

Comment: I am unable to figure out yet. I am trying to use RegEX to see if it can do it, but usure if I can highlight part of a string.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, that's not possible. One approach I would suggest is maybe storing the different string parts of Column B in multiple columns and concatenating.